Bin producing unexpected results
I use container insights and the following query shows an even chart:
ContainerLogV2
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m)


But when I want to group it by Computer, I suddenly see gaps:
ContainerLogV2
| summarize count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 10m), Computer


Is my query wrong?

Can you create a reproducable sample here to verify what is going on. Without having your real data it is hard to tell.

Maybe the Computer column is just empty which then produces the gaps in between. Maybe you could add a snapshot of your data table.

I tried to search for empty values, which yielded no results (isempty, isnull, "").

There are results in those "missing" time-bins, with the correct computer-info and it event shows up in the results (it seems I had a bug in my query the first time I filtered them). Seems to be a bug in their charting lib.

I have seen similar behaviour. In my case the number of results was limited. By default the log analytics workspace seem to be limited to 1000 results.

Haven you tried increasing the results limit?

True, that fixes the graph for me. Although I still don't understand why it works with only one group.
